# LINQ with inner enumerable query

Tags: linq

I'm struggling to get my head around LINQ.  In the example below I have three meetings. Jane Doe is assigned to two of those meetings. But the code below which I think should produce an answer of two is showing three meetings.  Any ideas?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person() { Name = "John Doe" };
        Person p2 = new Person() { Name = "Jane Doe" };
        Person p3 = new Person() { Name = "Alan Doe" };
        Meeting m1 = new Meeting() { MeetingName = "Meeting One", People = new List<Person> { p1, p2 } };
        Meeting m2 = new Meeting() { MeetingName = "Meeting Two", People = new List<Person> { p2, p3 } };
        Meeting m3 = new Meeting() { MeetingName = "Meeting Three", People = new List<Person> { p1, p3 } };
        List<Meeting> allMeetings = new List<Meeting>{m1,m2,m3};
        //Now, find all the meetings that Jane Doe is in
        var results = allMeetings.Select(x => x.People.Select(y => y.Name == "Jane Doe").Any());
        Console.WriteLine(results.Count().ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Meeting
{
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
x.People.Select(y => y.Name == "Jane Doe").Any()
```

You're using `Select`, which is a projection, when you meant to use `Where`, for filtering. Given that `Select` never filters out any items, you're basically returning all meetings where there are *any* attendees at all.

In fact, you can do it more simply anyway, as `Any` can take a condition:

```
x.People.Any(y => y.Name == "Jane Doe")
```

Comment: +1: It's a common mistake for beginners to confuse `Select` with `Where`.

Comment: As usual, @JonSkeet saves the day

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Indeed. I nearly closed the question as a typo, but then I figured it might be useful to others. They'd have to find it first, of course.

Comment: I was just about to answer and you jumped in and beat me to it. Do you have access to the "two minutes earlier than everyone else" version of SO?!

Comment: @TomChantler: Skeet just thinks his answer and SO types it out for him.